# When I enable APC I can't login to WordPress admin

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, apc

Hey guys I have enabled APC on my VPS but now I can't access my WordPress backend due to a 500 error. The rest of my site works fine, I just can't login to WordPress. Here are my settings for APC:

```
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_segmetns=1
apc.shm_size = 32M
apc.num_files_hint = 512
apc.user_entries_hint = 4096
apc.ttl = 7200
apc.use_request_time=1
apc.user_ttl = 7200
apc.gc_ttl = 3600
apc.cache_by_default = 1
apc.filters
apc.mmap_file_mask = "/tmp/apc.XXXXXX"
apc.file_update_protection = 2
apc.enable_cli = 0
apc.max_file_size = 2m
apc.stat=0
apc.stat_ctime=0
apc.canoonicalize=1
apc.write_lock=1
apc.report_autofilter=0
apc.rfc1867=0
apc.rfc1867_prefix =upload_
apc.rfc1867_name=APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_freq=0
apc.rfc1867_ttl=3600
apc.include_once_override=0
apc.lazy_classes=0
apc.lazy_functions=0
apc.coredump_unmap=0
apc.file_md5=0
apc.preload_path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue may be related to this: http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2006/02/13/adventures-with-wp-cache2-apc/

Try adding this as your filter: `apc.filters = wp-cache-config`

Comment: Well, I don't get the errors anymore but now after I login I get a 404 page.

Comment: Do you have any cache plugins installed? If so, you need to try clearing them.

Comment: No, I don't. I actually renamed my plugins folder just in case of them was interfering.

Comment: Do you have SuPHP enabled/installed? Sometimes it can interfere with APC.

Comment: Nope, I am using fcgi. When I use eAccelerator I can login just fine.

Answer (score 0):

my problems where gone with this on the apc.ini file
apc.filters = "-(.*apc.php)|(.*/wp-admin/.*.php)|(.*/phpmyadmin/.*.php)"